# Best way to add documentation to vb.net project pointing to an article on the web

Tags: vb.net, class, documentation, code-documentation

I found a great article here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18204/ASP-NET-controls-to-display-enum-values

where I studied it, learned a lot, and incorporated it as a new class library in my Visual Studio Solution.

Having borrowed the code and utilized in a web application, what is the best way to link up the original article on CodeProject to my Visual Studio solution (multiple projects) both so I can "bookmark" this article for later reference by me and my team member(s) and give credit to the original developer who came up with the idea. One idea I had would be an AboutBox in the EnumControls class library but the more I think about that it seems a bit stupid (I really only want some doc available at design time for my co-workers and for my future leaky brain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a works cited page (text file in your solution) and then comments in code files where the code is actually used. This gives you and the other developers some immediate context of where it came from, but the solution level text file provides an artifact in your software process.

The VB.NET XML comment (`'''`) would allow for IntelliSense documentation as well, which may be overkill, but it would be available to developers at code implementation time.